# Multiple Hboxes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have multiple Hboxes in JavaFX like this:

```
HBox hb = new HBox(10);
HBox hb2 = new HBox(10);
HBox hb3 = new HBox(10);
HBox hb4 = new HBox(10);
etc..
```

I want to put the hbox creation in a loop, but I am not really sure how to do that.

I've tried it like this:

```
HBox[] array = new HBox[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    array[i] = new HBox(10);
}
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to add some content to the hboxes:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at OptieScherm.start(OptieScherm.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more`
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. Not really sure what the question is.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question

Comment: But the code you posted isn't throwing that exception, is it? Which line is throwing the null pointer exception? Are you deliberately not initializing the last element of the array?

Comment: I've figured out my i was getting an error, I tried to call array[3]... My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
ArrayList<HBox> boxes = new ArrayList<HBox>();
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    Hbox h = new HBox(10);
    boxes.add(h);
}
```

Then just access them out of the list

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can by doing the following:

first: find your element taht you want to add the HBoxes to it.

Second create a global HBox like:

```
HBox hb = null;
```

Then loop and assign to the variable the HBox instance Then assign the created HBox to the root elemnt:

```
for(int i =0: i < your_number_of_HBoxes; i++){
   hb = HBox hb = new HBox(10);
   root.getChildren().add(rect);
}
```